# Running Ubuntu in VM -- No Sound after upgrading to 22.10

Tags: sound, xrdp, 22.10, hyper-v, pipewire

I just updgraded from 22.04 to 22.10. I'm running Ubuntu in a Hyper-V VM. I had pulse audio configured and working and sound was working well using xrdp-sink as an output device prior to the upgrade. Post upgrade, I have no sound and the only audio output device is dummy output. xrdp-sink is no longer an option. I see that the upgrade seems to have moved me awa from pulseaudio and now there is Pipewire.

I tried to research a little and everything I could find was specific to pulse audio and Ubuntu 22.04 or prior. Not finding any info on getting this done 22.10. Wondering if anyone out there has successfully gotten audio configured on 22.10 when running in Hyper-V

Edit:  I did see a thread basically detailing how to remove pipewire and revert to pulseaudio, but my other limited research seems to show pipewire is the direction things are going. My hope is to get sound working using pipewire

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is that as of this writing, "out of the box," xrdp does not support sound redirection via pipewire. Therefore there is no xrdp-sink output device available.

Running the steps in the blog post below to compile and install a module to address. After following these steps and rebooting the ubunt vm resolved the issue for me and created an xrdp-sink output device.

https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18772

This is probably not a solution for an ubuntu installation on bare metal.  Then again, it's probably not an issue for bare metal installs in the first place.